# Calling function in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I encountered a problem in my program. I am using awk and I am trying to call a function in it.

```
function dots()
{
    for ((i= 0 ; i < $1; i++)); do
        echo "."
    done
}


awk '{k=$1; sub(/[^ ]+ /,"__",$0); $1=$1; print $0 "\t:", (dots k) }'
```

Then I try to call the function and pass `k` as the first argument (`k` is a number). Is there a way to call a function in awk?

Comment: Have you tried with parentheses, like so: `dots(k)`?

Comment: yes and it doesn't work

Comment: Oops, totally missed, it's a shell function. See the answer below by Jens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just can't call shell functions from awk.
You have to write an equivalent awk function, e.g. add this to your awk script:

```
function dots(n) {while(n-- > 0) print "."}
```

Comment: Sounds good, I posted my suggestion as an alternative answer. You might want to tweak yours to check for n being positive - if it was called with a negative number it'd spin off into a [near] infinite loop. To use a loop like that robustly to create a string of contiguous dots (the normal use-case for a function like this rather than having it print the string itself) would then be something like `function dots(n,   x) { while(n-- > 0) x=x "."; return x }`.

Comment: Great answer. One nit: `e.g. place this at the top of your awk script`...  Since awk prescans the entire script, the function can appear anywhere between the rules of a program. [There is no need to put the definition of a function before all uses of the function.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Definition-Syntax.html#Definition-Syntax)

Comment: @dawg Thanks for your insightful remark, I have modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The way to efficiently create a string of n dots with awk is

```
function dots(n) { return gensub(/ /,".","g",sprintf("%*s",n,"")) }
```

The above uses GNU awk for gensub(), with other awks you can use a variable and gsub():

```
function dots(n,  x) { x=sprintf("%*s",n,""); gsub(/ /,".",x); return x }
```

In the unlikely event that you really do want newlines after every `.` then change `/ /,"."` to `/ /,".\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into similar problem and resolved the issue through writing awk function.
We can't just call shell functions from awk. We need to write awk function inside the awk command as shown below:

```
awk '
function dots()
{
    for ((i= 0 ; i < $1; i++)); do
        echo "."
    done
}
{k=$1; sub(/[^ ]+ /,"__",$0); $1=$1; print $0 "\t:", (dots k) }'
```