# How to access the prefix when using uniq -c

Tags: dash-shell

I encountered a problem in my program. I have a list of files and I sort them with this code to find out the 10 most frequent file types in the list.

```
find $DIR -type f | file -b $SAVEFILES | cut -c1-40 | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```

My output looks like this

```
    168 HTML document, ASCII text
    114 C source, ASCII text
    102 ASCII text
     33 ASCII text, with very long lines
     30 HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with 
     26 HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon
     21 C source, UTF-8 Unicode text
     20 LaTeX document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with
     15 SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
     12 LaTeX document, ASCII text, with very lo
```

What I want to do is to access the values before the file types and replace them #. I can fdo that with a for loop but first I have somehow access them.

the expected output is something like this:

```
   __HTML document, ASCII text               : ################
   __C source, ASCII text                    : ###########
   __ASCII text                              : ##########
   __ASCII text, with very long lines        : ########
   __HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with : #######
   __HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon: ####
   __C source, UTF-8 Unicode text            : #### 
   __LaTeX document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with: ###
   __SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image      : #
   __LaTeX document, ASCII text, with very lo: #
```

EDIT: The # are not representing the exect number in my example. First line should have 168 #, second 114 # and so on

Comment: See answer to your last question:  [Calling function in awk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43027602/3776858)

Comment: well i tried that and it didnt work

Comment: Why do you removed bash tag?

Comment: Your recent edit removed the expected output and made the answers seem to be unable to produce what the question now sounds like you are asking for.  I have reverted it.  Please be invited to further refine your question, but don't make it harder to understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this:

```
| while read -r n text; do printf "__%s%$((48-${#text}))s: " "$text"; for ((i=0;i<$n;i++)); do printf "%s" "#"; done; echo; done
```

Change `48` according to your needs.

Output with your input:

```
__HTML document, ASCII text                       : ########################################################################################################################################################################
__C source, ASCII text                            : ##################################################################################################################
__ASCII text                                      : ######################################################################################################
__ASCII text, with very long lines                : #################################
__HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with         : ##############################
__HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon        : ##########################
__C source, UTF-8 Unicode text                    : #####################
__LaTeX document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with        : ####################
__SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image              : ###############
__LaTeX document, ASCII text, with very lo        : ############
```

Comment: Important: I‘ve replaced `<=` by `=` to fix a bug.

Answer (score 1):

A shell loop is never the right way to manipulate text, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

You can do what you asked for with this awk command:

```
$ awk '{printf "%-40s: %s\n", substr($0,9), gensub(/ /,"#","g",sprintf("%*s",$1,""))}' file
HTML document, ASCII text               : ########################################################################################################################################################################
C source, ASCII text                    : ##################################################################################################################
ASCII text                              : ######################################################################################################
ASCII text, with very long lines        : #################################
HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with : ##############################
HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon: ##########################
C source, UTF-8 Unicode text            : #####################
LaTeX document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with: ####################
SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image      : ###############
LaTeX document, ASCII text, with very lo: ############
```

but the right way to do this is to get rid of everything from `cut` on and just do something like this:

```
find "$DIR" -type f | file -b "$SAVEFILES" |
awk '
{ types[substr($0,1,40)]++ }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_desc"
    for (type in types) {
        printf "%-*s: %s\n", 40, type, gensub(/ /,"#","g",sprintf("%*s",cnt[type],""))
        if (++cnt == 10) {
            break
        }
    }
}
'
```

The above use GNU awk for sorted_in and gensub() and the 2nd one is untested since you only provided sample input for the last part, printing the "#"s

Answer (score 0):

The  perl approach, add:

```
| perl -lpE 's/\s*(\d+)\s(.*)/sprintf "__%-40s: %s", $2, "#"x$1/e'
```

output

```
__HTML document, ASCII text               : ########################################################################################################################################################################
__C source, ASCII text                    : ##################################################################################################################
__ASCII text                              : ######################################################################################################
__ASCII text, with very long lines        : #################################
__HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with : ##############################
__HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon: ##########################
__C source, UTF-8 Unicode text            : #####################
__LaTeX document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with: ####################
__SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image      : ###############
__LaTeX document, ASCII text, with very lo: ############
```

following @Ed's approach, just using `perl`

```
find "$DIR" -type f | file -b "$SAVEFILES" |\
  perl -lnE '$s{substr$_,0,40}++;}{printf"__%-40s: %s\n",$_,"#"x$s{$_}for(splice@{[sort{$s{$b}<=>$s{$a}}keys%s]},0,9)'
```

readable:

```
perl -lnE '
$seen{ substr $_,0,40 }++;
END {
   printf"__%-40s: %s\n", $_, "#" x $seen{$_}
      for( splice @{[sort { $seen{$b} <=> $seen{$a} } keys %seen]},0,9 )
}'
```

*Ps: Just note, the file utility just will test the files in the `$SAVEFILES` so, the `find ... | file -b $SAVEFILES` is pointless*