# Ignoring files from find utility using grep -v

Tags: bash

I have to sort files in my directory and subdirs by file utility and make diagram of 10 most frequent file types. It runs by

```
bash myfile -i [FILE_ERE]
```

so the FILE_ERE should be regex for every file and directory that should be ignored in my diagram. For example, when find out is

> testdirectory/hello1
> testdirectory/hello2
> testdirectory/newdir/hello3
> hello4

and my $FILE_ERE from arguments is "dir", it should ignore every file with "dir" and the output is

> hello4

I have this

```
input_name=$(file -b `find $DIR -type f | grep -v "$FILE_ERE"` | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | cut -d' ' -f 2-)
input_number=$(file -b `find $DIR -type f | grep -v "$FILE_ERE"` | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

But my regex isn't working correctly for some inputs, like FILE_ERE="ˆh" etc.

Comment: ROLF, favorite homework theese days... http://stackoverflow.com/q/43028856/632407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use find directly to [ignore your pattern](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-command-exclude-ignore-files/):

Using globing expresssion: FILE_ERE="h*" (all files starting with h)

```
find "${DIR}" -type f ! -name "${FILE_ERE}" -exec file -b {} +
```

Using regex: FILE_ERE="^.*/h.*$" (all files starting with h):

```
find "${DIR}" -type f ! -regex "${FILE_ERE}" -exec file -b {} +
```

Note that it is usually better to use `-exec` to process `find` output.

EDIT: Thanks @chepner for the suggestions.

NOTE: The regex much match the all file path, so to match all the files starting with `9`, you need to use the regex `^.*/9.*`. You can also use `-name "9*"`. This requires a globing expression, not a regex.

Comment: `-exec file -b {} +` would cut down on the number of calls to `file` (also note the quotes around `{}` are optional).